# Wrong encoding when load html stream from c# webbrowser to htmlagilitypack

Tags: encoding, html-agility-pack

I have a winform app to show a html web page. When the user click a button, I want to get some Nodes from html code. In my webBrowser every is fine. When I try to decode the class from a specific node witch the encoding is in Greek, wrong encoding appears.

**Code:**

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.Load(webBrowser1.DocumentStream);
var ShopName = ShopData.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='shop cf']").ToList()[0].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='shop-name']").ToList()[0].InnerText;
```

I had tried to change Web Browser Encoding (WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted). I had also tried to change the HtmlAgilityPack Load, by adding greek encoding

Any Ideas?

Comment: is this works for normal web pages

Answer (score 0):

When you document.load(), you can ask it to detect the encoding automatically or supply the encoding:

```
document.load(webBrowser1.DocumentStream, true);
```

or

```
document.load(webBrowser1.DocumentStream, Encoding.UTF8);
```